# Object.to_mesh(): required parameter "settings" not specified

Tags: python, scripting

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
ob = C.object

print(ob.data.vertices[0].co, "- Vert 0 (original)")

me = ob.to_mesh(scene=C.scene, apply_modifiers=True, settings='RENDER')

bpy.data.meshes.remove(me)
```

this is the code and i am getting this error, since i have specifies the value for setting parameter then why the error occurs

```
  me = obj.to_mesh(scene=scene, apply_modifiers=True, setting='RENDER')
  TypeError: Object.to_mesh(): required parameter "settings" not specified
```

Comment: In the line above the error you have the word `setting`. In the code above it you have `settings`. Which version do you have in your code?